# Using an open vs closed clutch cover on a motorcycle with a dry clutch

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, performance

A common modification I've seen on motorcycles with a dry clutch is to replace the closed clutch cover with an open one.  Besides the visual and auditory differences, will I notice anything else (better performance, reliability, etc.)?  Will there be any drawbacks to using an open clutch cover? For example, how much will I have to worry about water and small debris?

Comment: Well an open one is definitely a "dry" clutch, lol! :D

Comment: Unless it's raining.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading through some of the Ducati forums has lead me to believe the selection between an open and closed clutch cover on these bikes is mostly for aesthetics. There is some consideration for cooling, but nothing which is earth shattering. So here is a list of pros and cons which I have compiled on the subject:

**Open vs Closed Clutch Covers -**

**PROS:**

- Aesthetics - stylizing availability is unlimited
- Slight cooling advantage
- An open aftermarket cover can be much stronger than the stock flimsy one
- Sound emanations from the clutch are more noticeable

**CONS:**

- Clutch is more exposed to damage if the bike is dumped in an accident
- Can possibly catch small road debris
- *Slight* possibility of clutch dust getting on the bike and rider
- Sound emanations from the clutch are more noticeable
- Rain may cause slight slippage from the clutch

You'll notice about the noise factor, the same exact statement is used as a Pro and a Con. That's because while it's a factor, it all depends on the rider's preference. For the most part it's about styling and what the owner wants. There isn't that much of a performance difference to really worry about it, but I guess if you want every last ounce of performance from a bike, you may want to think about it.

Comment: I run my bikes without clutch covers at all because I'm lazy and I think it looks cool. You should not do it, though, it's stupid and this post reminds me that I need to put them back on.